# Refactor with a ternary operator

Tags: swift, if-statement, methods

Here is my code which actually working as I expect :

```
static func imageName(for page: Int, isThumbnail: Bool) -> String {
    return isThumbnail ? "\(page)_thumb.jpg" : "\(page).jpg"
}

static func writeImageFile(with data: Data, issue: Issue, page: Int) throws -> URL {
    let path = MediaFileManager.issueImagesDirectoryURL(issue: issue)
    let imagePath = path.appendingPathComponent("\(imageName(for: page, isThumbnail: false))")
    let thumbPath = path.appendingPathComponent("\(imageName(for: page, isThumbnail: true))")
    try data.write(to: imagePath)
    try data.write(to: thumbPath)

    return path
}
```

I want the same result:
- create 2 different constants which append to the main path
- write 2 data to this 2 paths

Is that possible to refactor the writeImageFile()?

Comment: What exactly do you want achieve?

Comment: There is no if/else statement in that bit of the code so I don't see any use of a ternary operator?

Answer (score 0):

First of all String Interpolation applied to a string is redundant.

If you want to write the data (once) depending on `isThumbnail` you have to add it as parameter

```
static func writeImageFile(with data: Data, issue: Issue, page: Int, isThumbnail: Bool) throws -> URL {
    let url = MediaFileManager.issueImagesDirectoryURL(issue: issue)
    let imageURL = url.appendingPathComponent(imageName(for: page, isThumbnail: isThumbnail))
    try data.write(to: imageURL)
    return url
}
```